# How do I remove all pixels over a threshold that are connected to a given pixel? (data is between 0-1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, heatmap

I am training a ML model that generates a series of heatmaps for a given input image. Right now, I'm grabbing the highest intensity pixel as the prediction, but I'm hoping to grab the location of the second-most intense pixel that is **not** connected to the first blob. The data is single-channel with range [0,1] stored as a `numpy` 2d matrix.

What's the best approach here?

Edit: I've attached an image of what I'm trying to run it on. Each of the blocks (there are 8 columns, 5 rows) is a heatmap, and some of them have 2 regions of pixels close to 1. I want to get the location of the top two regions.

[Heatmap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82xeO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've added a picture to try to clarify.

Comment: See non-maximum suppression at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/ and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/

Comment: I will try it out, thanks!